# How to use loops with playsound in python?

Tags: python, python-playsound

I am making a morse code program so I need to use loops with playsound module to play the short and long beeps again and again.
The files are playing properly without a loop but when I add a loop I run into an error.

```
from playsound import playsound
import time

for i in range(0, 5):
    playsound('long.mp3')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    playsound('short.mp3')
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

> ```
> Error 263 for command:
>         open long.mp3
>     The specified device is not open or is not recognized by MCI.
>
>     Error 263 for command:
>         close long.mp3
>     The specified device is not open or is not recognized by MCI.
> Failed to close the file: long.mp3
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\achin\PycharmProjects\Morse code\ok.py", line 5, in <module>
>     playsound('long.mp3')
>   File "C:\Users\achin\PycharmProjects\Morse code\venv\lib\site-packages\playsound.py", line 72, in _playsoundWin
>     winCommand(u'open {}'.format(sound))
>   File "C:\Users\achin\PycharmProjects\Morse code\venv\lib\site-packages\playsound.py", line 64, in winCommand
>     raise PlaysoundException(exceptionMessage)
> playsound.PlaysoundException: 
>     Error 263 for command:
>         open long.mp3
>     The specified device is not open or is not recognized by MCI.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using the with statement?
it would look something like this:

```
from playsound import playsound
import time

with open('long.mp3') as long_beep, open('short.mp3') as short_beep:
  for i in range(0, 5):
    playsound(long_beep)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    playsound(short_beep)
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

---

dditionally, it seems it may be a bug(?) with playsound, try downgrading to playsound 1.2.2 (`pip install playsound==1.2.2`) and try **your** code again

Comment: I am getting another error this time: - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\achin\PycharmProjects\Morse code\ok.py", line 4, in <module>
    with 'long.mp3' as long_beep, 'short.mp3' as short_beep:
AttributeError: _ _enter_ _

Comment: Try adding the open function, see edited answer

Comment: It is still not working. Is there any other module I can try that will work with loops ?

Comment: there's pydub (you will need ffmpeg as well to be able to play mp3) and pyaudio (a bit complex). There is a better way to work with this than using loops, i would say. You could store the beeps and their order as a list like [s, l, l] (where s stands for short beep and l for long beep). Then you could write a function that takes the list as input, constructs a sound file according to the contents, and returns it. Would work with playsound too